# SSH my Windows 10 VM

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, windows-10

I have two computers. The OS of the first one is Ubuntu and I am using a Windows VM (VirtualBox) on the second computer. I use a `Bridge Adapter` with the VM. Right now I am able to ping the VM, but if I want to SSH, I got `port 22: Connection Refused`. Be aware that the firewall is off on the VM. I also installed Bash/Ubuntu on that VM so that I can use Linux command lines. `openssh-server` is preinstalled when I installed Bash/Ubuntu.

I tried to connect to my VM with `ssh username@ip_address`.

In that scenario, what is the best way to SSH the Windows 10 VM from Ubuntu?

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

In the Settings > Apps, OpenSSH-Client and OpenSSh-Server are already installed :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doing a quick search, it seems Windows 10 has SSH as an optional feature. This means the feature has to be installed before you are able to SSH into it.

Microsoft outlines those guidelines here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

In your case you will want to install the SSH server feature. Install the SSH client if you would like to SSH from Windows to a different machine.

Comment: Maybe I should've said that .... I installed bash/Ubuntu on windows 10. So in using bash, I realized openssh-server is install by default.

Comment: The Link you posted solved my problem